# Change values in the innermost part of PHP associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

I would like to append a string to the values of a nested associative array in PHP.

The following is my array

```
$styles = array(
    'Screen' => array(
        "master.css",
        "jquery-jvectormap-1.0.css"),
    'handheld' => array("mobile.css") 
     );
```

Looping over it to change it in the following way fails.

```
foreach($media as $medium => $filename)
foreach($filenames as &$filename)
    $filename = "/styles/".$filename;
```

Prefixing `$medium` with `&` just causes a syntax error.

This also fails.

```
function prepend($prefix,$string)
{
return $prefix.$string;
}

foreach($media as &$medium)
  $medium = array_map(prepend("/styles"),$medium);
```

What is the simplest way to prefix `"/styles/"` to those `css` filenames given this data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$styles = array(
    'Screen' => array(
        "master.css",
        "jquery-jvectormap-1.0.css"),
    'handheld' => array("mobile.css") 
     );

foreach($styles as $k=>$v){
    foreach($v as $a=>$b){
        $styles[$k][$a] = '/styles/'.$b;
    }
}

print_r($styles);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach($styles as $medium => &$filenames) {
  foreach($filenames as &$filename) {
    $filename = "/styles/".$filename;
  }
}
```

Some tips:

- Use braces to structure your nested code. This will give you (and php) a better understanding of what is you meant
- Use Indenting. This will give you a better overview.
- Name the Iterating-Variable using the singular of the Array-Variable (ie. foreach($apples as $apple)). This will give you an extra hint with which variable you're dealing with.

Good Luck!

Comment: Ah, my error with & was in prepending it to the key (here, medium) and not the value (here, filenames). Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($media as $medium => $filenames) {
    foreach($filenames as $key => $filename) {
        $media[$medium][$key] = "/styles/" . $filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't this modify a copy of $filename?